# Keras GridSearch model prediction

Tags: python, numpy, keras, scikit-learn

I'm battling with a weird issue that I can't seem to figure out.

So, I used `KerasClassifier` and `GridSearch` to build and search for the best parameters for my model. This part worked fine.

After this, I tried predicting on my test data which is where the weird thing happened.
Assuming my grid_search object is `grid` and my test data is `X_test`, I noticed that the result of `grid.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)` is completely different from the result of `grid_best_estimator_.model.predict(X_test)`.

For more context, here's a sample of the result from `grid.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)`:

```
       1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1,
       1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1,
       1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 3])
```

and here's the result from the  `grid_best_estimator_.model.predict(X_test)`:

```
[[4.16748554e-01 3.44473362e-01 1.22328281e-01 1.16449825e-01]
 [3.47690374e-01 4.35497969e-01 9.62351710e-02 1.20576508e-01]
 [4.16748554e-01 3.44473362e-01 1.22328281e-01 1.16449825e-01]
 [4.16748554e-01 3.44473362e-01 1.22328281e-01 1.16449825e-01]
 [4.16748554e-01 3.44473362e-01 1.22328281e-01 1.16449825e-01]
 [4.48489130e-01 3.48928362e-01 1.13302141e-01 8.92804191e-02]
 [4.16748554e-01 3.44473362e-01 1.22328281e-01 1.16449825e-01]
 [2.65852152e-03 2.72439304e-03 5.55709645e-04 9.94061410e-01]
 [4.16748554e-01 3.44473362e-01 1.22328281e-01 1.16449825e-01]
 [4.16748554e-01 3.44473362e-01 1.22328281e-01 1.16449825e-01]
 [4.16748554e-01 3.44473362e-01 1.22328281e-01 1.16449825e-01]
 [1.14751011e-01 2.33341262e-01 3.13971192e-02 6.20510638e-01]
 [8.30730610e-03 1.07289189e-02 1.87594432e-03 9.79087830e-01]
```

In an attempt to debug this, I've tried to call np.argmax() on the output of `grid_best_estimator_.model(X_test)`. Then tried (result_of_best_estimator == result_of_model).all() which returns `False`.

So, am i missing something? Or do I misunderstand how this is supposed to work?

Comment: The first array looks like it returns a class id and the second array probabilities associated with each class. Did you check whether the rows of `grid_best_estimator_.model.predict(X_test)` each add up to 1?